# C# MessageBox dialog result

Tags: c#, dialog, messagebox

I want to make a MessageBox confirmation. Here is the message box:

```
MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Confirmation", messageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
```

And I want to make something like this (in pseudocode):

```
if (MessageBox.Result == DialogResult.Yes)
    ;
else if (MessageBox.Result == DialogResult.No)
    ;
else
    ;
```

How can I do that in C#?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
{ 
    //...
}
else if (result == DialogResult.No)
{ 
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also do it in one row:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Text", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

And if you want to show a messagebox on top:

```
if (MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, "Text", "Text", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

Comment: Yes but on "else if" if i put else if (MessageBox.Show("Text", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No) the message will re-apear

Comment: Of course but if you have only two choices Yes/No you have no reason to use else if...

Comment: Oh ok sry. At least you known this possibility :P
That I mainly want to mention is the TopMost property.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) and the previous answers don't help, you can retrieve the result using:

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("Message", "caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me ;)

Answer (score 2):

This answer was not working for me so I went on to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx). There I found that now the code should look like this:

```
//var is of MessageBoxResult type
var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Question);

// If the no button was pressed ... 
if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using if statements might I suggest using a switch instead, I try to avoid using if statements when possible.

```
var result = MessageBox.Show(@"Do you want to save the changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
switch (result)
{
    case DialogResult.Yes:
        SaveChanges();
        break;
    case DialogResult.No:
        Rollback();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```