# Catch the Yes No alert box - Confirmation box

Tags: vb.net

My following code works great and shows the confirmation box. I tried a lot but how do I catch the confirmation box message if a user has selected yes or no

```
Dim script As String = "<script type='text/javascript'> confirm('" + message + "');</script>"
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "AlertBox", script)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the message"? Don't you already have the message as `message` in the code you supplied? You've also mentioned *" I tried a lot"* - could you include some of your attempts?

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title.  All the cool kids know how to use the tags as a filter which makes it just noise.

Comment: @Santi I would like to pass the javascript variable to the vb.net string so I know if the user clicked on yes or no, so I can apply another condition, depending on the selection. so if confirmation= Yes do This etc

Comment: @Plutonix - Thanks that was a mistake

Comment: You can't get the result of a javascript confirm in the code-behind without storing it somewhere client-side (like in an `<asp:HiddenField>`) and then reading that from the code-behind. You may be better off using a [**`MessageBox`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777123/c-sharp-messagebox-dialog-result).